# How to delete a range of rows using javascript (Vanilla or JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to delete table rows in range from row with an ID "#deleteFirstRow" to row with an ID "#deleteLastRow". But all the other rows out of these two IDs should remain.
NB: I tried to search posted answers but did not get any working solution. Please help!

This is my table:

```
<table>

    <tr>doNotDeleteRow</tr>
    <tr>doNotDeleteRow</tr>
    <tr>doNotDeleteRow</tr>

    <tr id="deleteFirstRow">deleteRow</tr>
    <tr>deleteRow</tr>
    <tr>deleteRow</tr>
    <tr>deleteRow</tr>
    <tr id="deleteLastRow">deleteRow</tr>

    <tr>doNotDeleteRow</tr>
    <tr>doNotDeleteRow</tr>
    <tr>doNotDeleteRow</tr>

</table>
```

I tried this code:

```
$("table tr:not(#deleteFirstRow, #deleteLastRow)").remove();
```

But this code removes all rows except the ones with IDs: "#deleteFirstRow" and "#deleteLastRow".

What I want is to remove only rows between "#deleteFirstRow" and "#deleteLastRow" and also remove "#deleteFirstRow" and "#deleteLastRow".

So the expected result should be like below:

```
<table>

    <tr>doNotDeleteRow</tr>
    <tr>doNotDeleteRow</tr>
    <tr>doNotDeleteRow</tr>

    <tr>doNotDeleteRow</tr>
    <tr>doNotDeleteRow</tr>
    <tr>doNotDeleteRow</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Ofcourse I have data-attributes in my actual rows and they are numbered as well. They are also generated dynamically, so for now using row class is not an option. The only best option would be to use number range. Eg Delete from row number 1 up to row number 100, but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: How are the start/end rows selected? Are those ids hardcoded into markup, or do you add them dynamically?

Comment: @Teemu Those IDs are added when I click on the first row and the last row to delete in range.

Comment: Instead of setting id, store `rowIndex` of the clicked rows into variables. Then iterate `rows` collection (backwards, it's a live collection), and remove all the rows between the indices, including both of the clicked rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `slice` the collection of all rows based on the two boundary elements, then call `remove`.

```js
const rows = $('table tr');
rows.slice(rows.index($('#deleteFirstRow')), 
            rows.index($('#deleteLastRow')) + 1).remove();
```

```css
tr {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="doNotDeleteRow"><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr class="doNotDeleteRow"><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr class="doNotDeleteRow"><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr id="deleteFirstRow"><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr class="deleteRow"><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr class="deleteRow"><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr class="deleteRow"><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr id="deleteLastRow"><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr class="doNotDeleteRow"><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr class="doNotDeleteRow"><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr class="doNotDeleteRow"><td>11</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done with vanilla js

Here we loop through the rows till we hit a row with the a row with the id 'deleteFirstRow' then we set deleting to true and then we remove() every row until we hit the row id 'deleteLastRow' and we remove that row too.

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tr');
let deleting = false;
for (row of rows) {
  if (row.id == 'deleteFirstRow') {
    deleting = true;
  }
  if (row.id == 'deleteLastRow') {
    deleting = false;
    row.remove();
  }
  if (deleting) {
    row.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
  <table>
      <tr><td>doNotDeleteRow</td></tr>
      <tr><td>doNotDeleteRow</td></tr>
      <tr><td>doNotDeleteRow</td></tr>

      <tr id="deleteFirstRow"><td>deleteRow</td></tr>
      <tr><td>deleteRow</td></tr>
      <tr><td>deleteRow</td></tr>
      <tr><td>deleteRow</td></tr>
      <tr id="deleteLastRow"><td>deleteRow</td></tr>

      <tr><td>doNotDeleteRow</td></tr>
      <tr><td>doNotDeleteRow</td></tr>
      <tr><td>doNotDeleteRow</td></tr>

  </table>
```

Edit: fix typo